# Unable to push due to unstructured comment

Tags: git, git-push

I have a pushed commit in my feature branch which is not structured as per enforced policy. Now when I try to merge that branch into develop and push it, its giving me following error.

[image]

I have tried to amend the comment in the actual commit but it didn't work. Can anyone tell me how should I fix it.

Comment: This is not answerable. Policies are not set by Git, but by your remote's owner (by writing the `update` script). Ask the repository owner what his policy is. Asking us what your comment should be like is like asking us why your wife is angry with you - we're the wrong people to ask. Unless your remote's owner copy-pasted the policy script from [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#_enforcing_commit_message_format), judging by the error message (but they might have customised the logic while leaving the error message the same).

Comment: This is a policy specific to the project. You'll have to ask them.

Comment: It would be good to know the message contents and also the message policy configured in the remote repository. For example, the remote repository can enforce that all commit messages contain a string with a format like this: "ref: 123" with the purpose of linking a commit with some ticket on TRAC, Jira, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use git rebase to modify the history. After going to your branch, type

```
git rebase -i a8a28358058^
```

Change `pick` to `edit` in the line of the commit. Type

```
git commit --amend
```

and enter a well-formatted (per your company's policy) message. Type

```
git rebase --continue
```

to return back to the top of the tree and push that. Note that history editing will change all commit IDs starting with the one you edited.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the remote's owner is using a hook to check the commit message format. you can ask the owner what the message format is and if possible ask the owner to share the hook which you can re-use as .git/hooks/commit-msg to check your message format when making a commit.